# Custom credential Provider able to call on c# application?

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, credentials, provider

I'm currently working on integrating a `c#` gesture authentication program using the `kinect` into windows as a form of authentication for part of my final year project. Once the c# program authenticates, there will be an event fired if the gesture supplied is authenticated to be a valid gesture.

So my question is:

1. I'm currently using the `sampleHardWareEventCredentialProvider` from microsoft. Is it suitable for what I want to achieve?
2. Can the custom credential provider be coded in such a way that it can call my c# program to do the authenticating and return an event to the credentialProvider whether the authentication was a success or not? If yes, could anyone kindly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think that to create a custom Credential Provider you need to implement the ICredentialProvider  COM interface http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776042.aspx . You can do this using C# (maybe like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7859/Building-COM-Objects-in-C ). Are you already using SampleHardWareEventCredentialProvider with C# successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The sample hardware Credential Provider, certainly from what I've read, is made for what you're trying to do, as it;s currently geared-up for authentication a user via third-party hardware, such as fingerprint readers, etc.  One would imagine that Kinect would fit nicely into that model, assuming you could get the gesture element right!!  Also, bear in mind that the Credential Providers were written for Vista, so Kinect may not have been a glint in a MS-Dev's eye at the time.

In terms of your second point, about being able to call a C# application to do the authenticating, yes you certainly can, as I've done it this week myself using a WPF application to write a self-service password reset app.  I've not needed to return an event/data back to the Credential Provider from the C# application, as I've not needed to do that, but can't imagine that this is a massive pitfall.

Hope this helps.